# Get-GPOReport and Search For Matched Name Value

Tags: powershell, parsing, search, match, group-policy

I'm trying to use the PowerShell command 'Get-GPOReport' to get GPO information in XML string format so I can search it for sub-Element values with unknown and different Element tag names (I don't think XML Object format will work for me, so I didn't perform a cast with "[xml]"), but I haven't been able to parse the XML output so that I can grab the line or two after a desired "Name" Element line that matches the text I'm searching for.

After, I have been trying to use 'Select-String' or 'Select-XML' with XPath (formatting is unclear and I don't know if I can use a format for various policy record locations) to match text and grab a value, but I haven't had any luck.

Also, if anyone know how to search for GPMC GUI names (i.e. "Enforce password history") instead of needing to first locate back-end equivalent names to search for (i.e. "PasswordHistorySize"), that would also be more helpful.

The following initial code is the part that works:

```
$String = "PasswordHistorySize"     # This is an example string, as I will search for various strings eventually from a file, but I'm not sure if I could search for equivalent Group Policy GUI text "Enforce password history", if anyone knows how to do that.
$CurrentGPOReport = Get-GPOReport -Guid $GPO.Id -ReportType Xml -Domain $Domain -Server $NearestDC

If ($CurrentGPOReport -match $String) 
{
    Write-Host "Policy Found: ""$($String)""" -Foregroundcolor Green
    #
    #
    # The following code is what I've tried to use to get value data, without any luck:
    #
    $ValueLine1 = $($CurrentGPOReport | Select-String -Pattern $String -Context 0,2)
    $Value = $($Pattern = ">(.*?)</" ; [regex]::match($ValueLine1, $Pattern).Groups[1].Value)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking at this since yesterday and didn't understand why `Select-String` wasn't working, and I figured it out today... The report is stored as a multi-line string, rather than an array of strings. You could do a `-match` against it for the value, but `Select-String` doesn't like the multi-line formatting it seems. If you `-split '[\r\n]+'` on it you can get `Select-String` to find your string.

If you want to use RegEx to just snipe the setting value you can do it with a multi-line regex search like this:

```
$String = "PasswordHistorySize"     # This is an example string, as I will search for various strings eventually from a file, but I'm not sure if I could search for equivalent Group Policy GUI text "Enforce password history", if anyone knows how to do that.
$CurrentGPOReport = Get-GPOReport -Guid $GPO.Id -ReportType Xml -Domain $Domain -Server $NearestDC

$RegEx = '(?s)' + [RegEx]::Escape($String) + '.+?Setting.*?>(.*?)<'

If($CurrentGPOReport -match $RegEx)
{
    Write-Host "Policy Found: ""$String""" -Foregroundcolor Green

    $Value = $Matches[1]
}
```

I'm not sure how to match the GPMC name, sorry about that, but this should get you closer to your goals.

**Edit:** To try and get every setting separated out into it's own chunk of text and not just work on that one policy I had to alter my RegEx a bit. This one's a little more messy with the output, but can be cleaned up simply enough I think. This will split a GPO into individual settings:

```
$Policies = $CurrentGPOReport -split '(\<(q\d+:.+?>).+?\<(?:\/\2))' | Where { $_ -match ':Name' }
```

That will get you a collection of things that look like this:

```
<q1:Account>
          <q1:Name>PasswordHistorySize</q1:Name>
          <q1:SettingNumber>21</q1:SettingNumber>
          <q1:Type>Password</q1:Type>
        </q1:Account>
```

From there you just have to filter for whatever setting you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks! Your $RegEx string works for the specific value searched for in the example because the XML tag matches "Setting", but most values have different XML tags. All of the values I'm looking for should appear after a $String match and before the characters "</", back to the first ">" character.  Although there are instances where there are multiple string values, so ideally retrieve each string before each "</" until next "Name>" is reached. I started playing with RegEx to try to get this to work, but haven't found a working match yet. Suggestions?

Comment: Hm, you may be on to something there. Everything up to the next `Name>` can be done. Let me try some things and I'll get back to you. Might not be until Monday, I have a busy weekend ahead of me.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this with XPath, as you'll have more control navigating in the XML nodes:

```
[string]$SearchQuery = "user"
[xml]$Xml = Get-GPOReport -Name "Default Domain Policy" -ReportType xml
[array]$Nodes = Select-Xml -Xml $Xml -Namespace @{gpo="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Settings"} -XPath "//*"
$Nodes | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.Node.'#text' -match $SearchQuery} | ForEach-Object -Process {
    $_.Name #Name of the found node
    $_.Node.'#text' #text in between the tags
    $_.Node.ParentNode.ChildNodes.LocalName #other nodes on the same level
}
```

After testing we found that in the XML output of the Get-GPOReport cmdlet, the setting names does not always match that of the HTML output. For example: "Log on as a service" is found as "SeServiceLogonRight" in the XML output.